# My <p> is picking up a <Div>'s CSS? Why?

Tags: html, css

Yes I'm learning... I know it's not the best way but all my CSS is inline atm. If anyone has any advice it would be great.

My p tag title 'Big Valve Cylinder Heads' for some reason is picking up some css from a below div tag and changing color/underlining. Why does it do this?
If I remove the anchor tags everything is fine.

BUT - The first section 'Stroker Engine Kits' is all fine! and it's just the code copied!

See below:

http://5.77.57.189/~admin/productscopy.html

```
<div class="container">
<h1 style="padding-left:10px;">Cosworth Performance Products Distributors & Dealers </h1>

<div class="row">

    <div class="four columns">
        <p>Stroker Engine Kits</p>
            <div style="padding-top:10px;"><img src="images/stroker.jpg"></div>
            <div style="float:left;"><img src="images/arrow.gif"></div>
            <div style="width:170px; height:21px; background-color: #a8a9ad;"><p style="font-size:10px;"><a href="http://google.co.uk" style="text-decoration:none; padding-left:10px; ">More Information<a/></p></div>
    </div>

    <div class="four columns">
        <p>Big Valve Cylinder Heads</p>
            <div style="padding-top:10px;"><img src="images/20004544.jpg"></div>
            <div style="float:left;"><img src="images/arrow.gif"></div>
            <div style="width:170px; height:21px; background-color: #a8a9ad;"><p style="font-size:10px;"><a href="http://google.co.uk" style="text-decoration:none; padding-left:10px; ">More Information<a/></p></div>
    </div>

</div>
```

ALSO - Does anybody know how I can remove the white space between the image and the more information box underneath? Margin:0; isn't working!

Thanks guys :)

Comment: It's not picking up that css, the `<a>` has the active attribute on it. As if it was clicked. Check you element, it getting the class from `a:visited`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

welcome, good place to learn.

well you are not getting any css its just because you have `'<a>'` tag ( means you will make it a link so that make the border bellow of your p title.

if you remove the `'<a>'` will fix :)
see:

```
<a>
                <p>Big Valve Cylinder Heads</p>
                <div style="padding-top:10px;"><img src="images/20004544.jpg"></div>
                <div style="float:left;"><img src="images/arrow.gif"></div>
</a>
```

try use: https://jsfiddle.net/ so its more easy for us test and give a fast answer.

try like that
removing the p link from a:

```
<p>Big Valve Cylinder Heads</p>
<a>

                <div style="padding-top:10px;"><img src="images/20004544.jpg"></div>
                <div style="float:left;"><img src="images/arrow.gif"></div>
</a>
```

you can learn more here:
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_link.asp
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_href.asp

Comment: I want the image and 'more information' to link. But not the title. - thanks for the quick answers though

Comment: remove the title from <a> tag ok?

Comment: I understand yes, removing the <a> tag removes the hyperlink title. But I still want my image linked and the <a> tag was not linked to the title?

Answer (score 0):

You should add **display:block;** to all images inside your div to remove whitespace.

```
<div style="width:170px; height:21px; background-color: #a8a9ad;">
   <p style="font-size:10px;">
      <a href="http://google.co.uk" style="text-decoration:none; padding-left:10px; ">More Information<a/>
   </p>
</div>
```

Your end  tag is wrong, that's why everything is fine once you remove it. It should be

```
</a>
```

Then all will be fixed. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Check, you have a typo in the closing anchor tag in the bottom line. Things like this could lead to unpredictable behavior

```
<a/>
```

And also a good practice is to separate your CSS from HTML via putting your CSS rules in a separate CSS file.

Answer (score 0):

It's picking up the default css from the `<a>` tag actually. The `<a>` tag is typically used for a link which is why it's underlined and blue (like a default link).

You can override the `<a>` tag's css by adding a class to `<p class="paragraph">` and putting in css something like `.paragraph{text-decoration: none; color: black; }`. This would turn off the underline effect.

Or you can put a click event in the .js to send the user where you want them to go when they click on 'Big Valve Cylinder Heads'.